# Enlarging the omnibar in Safari 8

Tags: macos, safari, search

I am using Safari 8.0.2. Safari 8 introduced some really great features, but it made the omnibar tiny - it now occupies less than a third of the toolbar, and it seems impossible to adjust its size. I find this incredibly irritating. How can I enlarge it so that it fills the majority of the toolbar again? Is there an extension that does so?

Comment: Indeed, the address bar loses a lot a space. Have you tried setting up the tool bar, with right click? And resizing the end of the address bar with pressing Apple or Option?

Comment: I tried every combination and order of those actions I could imagine, all to no effect.